# Transform element does not work in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to make a simple transform transition animation using css and js so I coded this:

**(test page)**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                margin:0;padding:0;
            }
            body{
                background-color:#000;
            }
            .fly-in-text{
                list-style:none;
                position:absolute;
                left:50%;
                top:50%;
                transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            }
            .fly-in-text li{
                display:inline-block;
                color: #d98c12;
                margin-right:50px;
                font-family:Open Sans,Arial;
                font-weight:300;
                font-size:4em;
                transition: all 2.5s ease;
            }
            .fly-in-text li:last-child{
                margin-right:0;
            }
            .fly-in-text.hidden li{
                opacity:0;
            }
            .fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(1){ transform: translateX(-200px) translateY(-200px); }
            .fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(2){ transform: translateX(20px) translateY(-20px); }
            .fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(3){ transform: translateX(-150px) translateY(-80px); }
            .fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(4){ transform: translateX(-150px) translateY(-200px); }
            .fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(5){ transform: translateX(10px) translateY(-200px); }
            .fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(6){ transform: translateX(-300px) translateY(200px); }
            .fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(7){ transform: translateX(20px) translateY(-20px); }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="fly-in-text hidden">
            <li>W</li>
            <li>E</li>
            <li>L</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>O</li>
            <li>M</li>
            <li>E</li>
        </ul>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.fly-in-text').removeClass('hidden');
                },500);
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that this page is just a test page to see if the js and css transitions works properly or no and as you can see it works correctly but whenever I want to add these codes to my main site which uses Bootstrap ,it won't work. Here is my main site code source:

**(main site)**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Daygostar Home Page</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/fly-text.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">
  <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="header-text">
                <ul class="fly-in-text hidden">
                    <li>W</li>
                    <li>E</li>
                    <li>L</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                    <li>O</li>
                    <li>M</li>
                    <li>E</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/button1.png" width="300" height="300"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/button2.png" width="300" height="300"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.fly-in-text').removeClass('hidden');
                },500);
            })();
    </script>
```

Notice that when I delete this line of code which connects the main site to Bootstrap css ,the transition/transform of the text works ...

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So why the code does not work when I link Bootstrap css and when I delete it works properly?

> I have inserted the styles of text transforms into a staggered file named 'fly-text.css'
>
> The javascript part of test page is correctly place in main site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the class `.hidden`. Line #6544 in boostrap.css (NOT minified version).

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Remove it and everything should work fine.

Comment: OMG! After 3 days searching around, finally it works :) ... Thank you very very much...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the sequence of Loading the CSS files or keep the bootstrap.min.css at the end of the page.

Comment: What do you mean by keeping the css bootstrap at the end of the page? Would you explain more please?

Comment: keep the <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> inside  <body> </body>  tag  or after </html> tag. it is not a good practice but see if it works.